# How to apply the Location.url() that I changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to so a angular redirect however I have only got part of the way. At the moment I have managed to change the URL however I want to then go to that url instead of just changing it.

```
    scope.socialReturnUrl = function ( path ) {
      location.url( path + 'assessment' );
    };
```

My below code seems to only change the URL or the location. What am I missing to apply this so it gets redirected?

I should point out that I've already tried to use scope$apply() however this causes the below error:

scope$apply is not defined

I already have scope as a dependency but I havent got a apply dependency is this something that I need?

Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: You should show how you're calling this method.

Comment: Show all your code. It's difficult to know what location refers to in your exemple. The $apply function is on the scope, it's not `scope$apply`, it's `$scope.$apply()`, and on a second note you shouldn't call $apply in a function which is evaluated on the digest loop (which you are certainly doing in your example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right... I fixed this myself.

Apparently location.url() will not do a full refresh as seen in the documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

However you need to add the dependency $window and use the below code to make the page do a full page reload.

window.location.href = path + 'assessment';

Comment: Took a look at ui-router. That supports location applying, states, partial reloads and a lot more.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service in your controller in order to change the url. If you don't, you'll be calling the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object instead, which is not what you should be doing.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.socialReturnUrl = function ( path ) {
            $location.url( path + 'assessment' );
        };
    }])
```

Comment: If I had put all the code I was using you'd be able to see I already tried this way. My bad for not explaining myself properly.